# Adding a tapGestureRecognizer to a Custom UIView with xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

Background: I have an array of questions that are the basis for setting up a bunch of uiviews and laying them out on the screen. Each uiview has a title and an imageview. I would like to add a tap gesture recognizer to the imageview and have the uiview be the gesture delegate.

The problem: Cannot get the gesture to be picked up by the uiview.

What I have tried so far: If I init the view in code with init with frame, instead of loading the xib through the main bundle with the viewcontroller as owner, works without modifying the gesture code. So I think the problem must lie in how and when to add the gesture recognizer. Currently im using a setup method which loads in the question name and then adds it there. Adding it in awake from nib doesnt work.

This is the code in the loop that loads each uiview

```
NSArray* bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QnA" owner:self options:nil];

QuestionAnswer *qa;
for (id object in bundle) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[QuestionAnswer class]])
        qa = (QuestionAnswer *)object;
    }

CGRect f = qa.frame;
f.origin.x = x;
f.origin.y = y;
qa.frame = f;
[self.view addSubview: qa];
[qa setup:[questions objectAtIndex:i ]];
```

And this is the "setup" method in the QuestionAnswer class

```
-(void)setup:(NSString *)label
{
    self.afl.text = label;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    tgr.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

}
```

QuestionAnswer implements UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. I have a breakpoint at the firstline of imageTapped and it never gets there. I have also tried applying the gesture recognizer directly to the imageview to no avail.

The viewcontroller is in a splitview controller, dont think that has relevance as the recognizer worked when I init the view in code. :/

Comment: what does your imageTapped method do?

Comment: What class is `-(void)setup:(NSString *)label` found in?  What is it's superclass?  Is it a UIView?

Comment: imageTapped is never called. (QuestionAnswer class)Yes UIView is its superclass

Answer (score 0):

Add the gesture recognizer in a viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I may be mistaken but i dont think UIView has a viewDidLoad method, atleast it doesnt autocomplete or get called if i add it. I dont want to call the gesture recognizer from the parent VC as it would break modularity.